# I discovered a mistake in my application after being accepted to a master's program. What should I do? Will my offer be rescinded?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, rejection

I have been accepted to Duke for the MS in ECE program for Fall 2021.
I just checked my proof of application and there has been an error. It lists my minor as "Economics" whereas I have no such minor.

I have not deliberately tried to falsify my education, I think it could've been a human error on my part (I wanted to specify minor as Electronics since it only mentioned Electrical Engineering as the major). I only saw this right now, and I didn't catch the mistake when I first submitted the application or I would've contacted the admissions team right then. I was able to view this from my "proof of application" which is for personal use only.

I have been accepted to a STEM MS and I don't see how not having an Economics minor should change anything.

Duke's my first choice, I don't know what to do.

Should I email said university about the error? I don't think I made the mistake. Will they rescind my application?

Comment: They got your transcripts, right? Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that it would be rescinded if you tell them what happened and apologize. But failing to tell them might lead to some future charge of fraud, which could be grounds for expulsion. It might depend on how prominent the minor is in the application materials.

It is possible that the error was already noticed and dismissed since your transcripts show your coursework. So your informing them is just "In an abundance of caution, ..." statement.

No one can guarantee an outcome (other than the university), but errors happen. It might have been a bigger issue had you named Math or CS as a minor since that might have been a part of the decision to accept.